something with nim or mim
I can't quite remember but I have watched this many times, I think, but I haven't watched it in years.
It has to do with what looked like a stuffed bunny but it came in this tiny box and was like some alien or something later this bunny was caught and experimented on and two children a brother and sister found this box and released the bunny. And then saved the bunny from the scientist people.
It may have had something to do with mimsy or something, I don't know...
I have ADHD so the order and stuff may be terrible and not very easy to understand. It is in English and I think it may have been around 2009ish maybe. The year is very uncertain this is just about the time I may have watched it.

if i remember it had sad bits near the end...

Welcome to Movies & TV!(http://movies.stackexchange.com/tour) Please add any details you know: Country of origin (or at least language), actors you recognize (or even just what they look like), was it in theaters or only on TV, any other minor plot points. The more you can give us, the more likely we can help you.

My guess: The Last Mimzy (2007)

It's The Last Mimzy a 2007 film. The main plot revolves around a toy rabbit. You can find information about it in the link provided.

You might want to elaborate, though, in which way it fits to the descriptions from the question to flesh out the answer a little more.

OoO arigato gozaimashta! i am very disappointed in my own memory for not being able to come up with the name but thank you
